# Can “been” used in the same sentence twice?

Tags: past-participles

Is it natural to use the word “been” twice in the same sentence

> I’ve been tapering off my smoking and it’s been going well so far.

> I’m tapering off my smoking and it’s been going well so far.

Which of the two is more natural/grammatically correct? If neither is correct, how do I rephrase it?

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can use "been" twice in a sentence, but as user3169 has pointed out, it's not the best way to write *this* sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I would stay with perfect tense since it's continuing action. But to avoid the repeater, I would write:

> I’ve been tapering off my smoking and it’s going well so far.

You don't need the second *been*, especially with *so far* in there.

Comment: The fact that it's a *continuing / ongoing action* is what justifies the continuous verb ***tapering***. But that could just as well have been ***I’m** tapering off my smoking and it’s going well so far*. Not that there's anything *wrong* with Present Perfect ***I have been*** here - it just not obvious to me there's any particularly strong argument *in favour* of using it. And if I were a learner, I'd rather learn that I don't need to bother with complicated verb forms very often - certainly not in *this* context, where Simple Present + Continuous is all that's needed.